# Removing an Appended " In front of Every Column

Tags: mysql

I found a CSV database of Cities/ZIP/GPS, and when I imported it, it added a " infront of the columns.
[alt text http://www.grabup.com/uploads/58754a865eebd94c9aafaf7444b52d15.png?direct](http://www.grabup.com/uploads/58754a865eebd94c9aafaf7444b52d15.png?direct)
I don't want to go in for 33,000 entries and do this manually, is there a query I can run that will remove the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not a MySql expert but this should work: (based on my similar experience in Sql Server)

UPDATE table_name SET col_name = REPLACE(col_name, '"', '')

For more info on the REPLACE and other string parsing functions, see here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 2):

in sql server you coud do:

```
update mytable set state= substring(state,2,29)
```

change the "29" to whatever the actual length is.

I am sure mysql must have equivalent syntax.

Repeat for each field, it looks like there is only a handful of them.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could filter the original csv document - isn't that easier?

Comment: Or even get a proper CSV scanner that deals with the data that was given!